# First order conditions - derivatives

Tags: derivatives

$$L = (x_11)^{\frac{1}{2}}(x_12)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

My attempt

$$\frac {\partial L}{\partial x_11} = \frac 12 {x_11}\sqrt{x_12}$$

Answer

$$\frac {\partial L}{\partial x_11} = \frac 12 \sqrt{\frac {x_12}{x_11}}$$

I don't understand how ${x_11}$ gets inside the radical as the denominator?

Even if my attempt and the answer are equivalent (I assume they are?) I'd still like to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_11} (x_11)^{\frac{1}{2}} (x_12)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}(x_11)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{x_12} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{x_12}}{\sqrt{x_11}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x_12}{x_11}}$ if I have not misunderstood anything. (remember the following rule : $a^nb^n = (ab)^n$ and let $a=x_12, b=\frac{1}{x_11}$ and $n=\frac{1}{2}$)

Comment: Ah forgot to take one off the exponent, wow my differentiation is rusty.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help ! If you got the answer you needed it would be nice if you marked it as accepted to "close of" the question :)

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to...you'd think there'd be a big button but I can't see anything on this page, or my profile

Comment: There should be a grey check mark next to the answer, below the up- and downvotes. You can press it to make it green. If there isn't then I guess it is not possible for some reason :)

Comment: Ah got it, thanks!